# UK Visa application - should I mention my previous refusals?

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals

I'm applying for a short term student visa in UK to attend a summer school. 
I have applied for UK visit visa two times before and was refused.
The first was on 2008 because I did not submit a bank statement 
The Second was on 2014 because the officer was not convinced that I will be back home.

Now, Must I mention the 2 past refusals in my application for a short term student visa. I'm afraid to get refused as I have already paid the summer school fees which covers accommodation, transportation and meals.

Comment: They can easily check what would not mentioning these refusals achieve?

Comment: If you don't mention and they will find out, be prepared to be barred from UK for 10 years and also further visa refusals from other countries too.

Comment: The refusals were from deficiencies in your application.  You should use the information you gained from these refusals to strengthen your next application.  The official processing the application will most likely react favorably to someone who understands the deficiencies in an earlier application and corrects them; they will certainly, as others have said, react extremely unfavorably to any form of deception.

Answer (score 7):

Lots of people with a history of refusals like to think about not disclosing them because a tainted history may have a bad effect on fresh applications.  The UK knows about that too, so [Parliament mandated that every applicant for a UK visa of any sort had to enrol their biometrics](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2007/30/crossheading/biometric-registration) starting 31 Jan 2008.

You may recall that when you applied earlier that part of the process involved [collecting your biometrics](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CQTFD7UacKg).  Those were entered in to a computer system and every time somebody submits a fresh application they compare biometrics to see if the person is already on the system.  It's a great way to find out if somebody is lying because it's really hard for a person to change their biometrics.

It means the use of biometrics obviates your question.  You can still try it in the hopes that the servers will be down, but (from personal experience) the last time their servers crashed they just held all the applications in a queue until the servers were fixed.  It took two weeks to get the servers on line again which is a good measure of their resolve to carry out Parliament's mandate.

In the current era if you get caught, they will use [Paragraph 320 of the Immigration Rules](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/422941/20150406_Immigration_Rules_-_Part_9_final_v4.pdf) to ban you on aggravating conditions for 10 years. They will then tell the USA and other members of the Commonwealth about it.

Adding...

They can also cross sort by credit card number (if used for visa payment or travel payment or travel reservations) or by address or by passport details. Biometrics is not the only way people get caught out.